# Topological proof for this set theory statement

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra of set (in a space $X$), such that any subcollection of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{A}$ is finite. Prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is finite.

I already found a boring brute force proof of this fact. But the finiteness property "smell" like a compactness argument of some sort - specifically, we seems to be lifting a local finiteness property to a global one. Hence I am looking for a slick purely topological proof of this fact. But for the life of me I can't figure out which topological structure to put on it to make the argument fall out. Anyone have any clues?

Thank you.

Comment: I don’t see anything that uses topology in an essential way. A nice argument with a slightly topological flavor is to define an equivalence relation on $X$ by $x\sim y$ iff $$\{A\in\mathscr{A}:x\in A\}=\{A\in\mathscr{A}:y\in A\}$$ and look at the quotient $Y=X/\!\!\sim$. If $q:X\to Y$ is the quotient map, $\{q[A]:A\in\mathscr{A}\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathscr{A}$ as an algebra. If $Y$ is infinite, it’s easy to construct a strictly decreasing sequence $\langle q[A_n]:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, which gives rise to the pairwise disjoint family $\{q[A_n]\setminus q[A_{n+1}]:n\in\Bbb N\}$. Thus, $Y$ ...

Comment: ... and hence also $\mathscr{A}$ must be finite.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I don't think the first reduction is really helpful. Also, "it’s easy to construct a strictly decreasing sequence": maybe I miss something obvious, but it does not seems so easy to me; sure, you can brute force through it using the most obvious approach, but all the technical details make for a very ugly proof, so it's far from a slick proof.

Comment: The first reduction allows you to talk about points instead of equivalence classes; it’s a convenience. And the technical details are pretty trivial. Fix $y\in Y$. For each $z\in Y\setminus\{y\}$ there is a $B_z$ in the image algebra such that $y\in B_z$ and $z\notin B_z$. Well-order $Z=Y\setminus\{y\}$, and let $z_0\in Z$ be arbitrary, and let $C_0=B_{z_0}$. Given $z_n$, let $z_{n+1}$ be the first element of $Z$ such that $C_n\cap B_{z_{n+1}}\subsetneqq C_n$, is there is such an element. Either you get an infinite strictly decreasing sequence of sets $C_n$, or you find that $\{y\}$ is ...

Comment: ... in the image algebra. The former is impossible, so $\{y\}$ is in the image algebra for each $y\in Y$, and you’re done. Speaking as a set-theoretic topologist, I consider this a standard and fairly trivial kind of construction. If you don’t, that’s fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: sorry if I am not clear about what I means by "not easy". Yes, as you mentioned, it's "trivial", in the sense that there is an obvious method that work (my proof is a slightly different from yours, but essentially the same ideas - in fact, I'm pretty sure it's shorter once all the details are filled in). But I need to write out every little details for the homework, and an obvious argument could balloon to pages. And the statement seems to sound too much like a compactness statement that I want to find out a slick topological proof for this.